# NameError: uninitialized constant with FriendlyId after migration to Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I just migrated to Rails4 from 3.12 and I use FriendlyId, which was working fine in Rails 3.12
I followed the instructions I found here http://richonrails.com/articles/friendlyid-and-rails-4#.U6fTOY1_v_4

so my gemfile features:

```
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.0.0'
```

Using friendly_id 5.0.4

But I keep getting the following error message:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant <Classname>::FriendlyId
```

for each Class that resorts to FriendlyId

I saw this [NameError in SongsController#index uninitialized constant Song::FriendlyId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175670/nameerror-in-songscontrollerindex-uninitialized-constant-songfriendlyid)
But in my case, bundle install doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you restarted your server after that?

Comment: Yes I did, to no avail.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am seeing this all of a sudden on new models that I've added to an existing app that already uses friendly_id.

Comment: I had a typo in my `extend FriendlyId` statement.

Comment: No, i haven't figured it out yet, alas...so i can't migrate my app to Rails 4.

Comment: I capitalized ID in FriendlyID instead of FriendlyId.

Comment: and does it now work for you ?

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem with Rails 4 - and I fixed it by restarting spring:

```
$ spring stop
```

I ran the console again and it went back to working.

Comment: If your not using spring you can just restart your rails server and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

make sure you restart the console after bundling.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and in my case I forgot this step:

```
# Change User.find to User.friendly.find in your controller
User.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure without seeing your code but you need to add `extend FriendlyId` to your model.

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :foo, use [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

In this example `:foo` is the attribute you want `friendly_id` to use to create the unique slug.

Comment: My code is the same as yours in my Client model,  except it's use: (with a :) then in my Product model, I have : extend FriendlyId   friendly_id :foo, :use => :scoped, :scope => :client (it works fine in Rails 3)

Comment: Did you try removing the ':'? I would try to match up exactly how they have it in their documentation. I believe using a colon is invalid syntax for the `extend` method.

Comment: Yes I did, it generates : syntax error, unexpected [, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    friendly_id :code, use [:slugged, :finders]

Comment: Besides, the syntax use: [:slugged, :finders] is perfectly valid and works fine in Rails 3

Comment: I changed it to : , :use => [:slugged, :finders] (as it is written in the documentation) but I'm still getting the same error message : NameError: uninitialized constant FriendlyId